# SQL script running with error while using sys.obejcts to pre-check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a script, its function is to create a stored procedure and before create it the script should have to check if it exists in DB, so I write the procedure like below, If I comment out first 2 lines the scripts will create procedure  successfully if the stored procedure not exist, but I add the first two lines, the SSMS will throw error:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[User_Own_Restore_From_Job]') AND type in (N'P'))

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_Own_Restore_From_Job]
    @dbname varchar(500),
    @backuppath varchar (500)
    AS


    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

        DECLARE @XPConfig int = 1

        --To keep the existing value
        SELECT @XPConfig = cast(value AS INT) FROM sys.configurations WHERE name LIKE 'xp_cmdshell';

        --Enabling xp_cmdshell for getting registry and creating directory structure
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
            RECONFIGURE with override


            -- To enable the feature.
            EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
            RECONFIGURE with override
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            --empty
        END CATCH

        DECLARE    @datapath nvarchar(500);
        DECLARE    @logpath nvarchar(500);

        --read data and log path details from registry
        EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup', N'SQLDataRoot', @datapath OUTPUT
        EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', @logpath OUTPUT

        SET @datapath=@datapath+'\Data';

        --creating a database folder if not already exists on log and data drives
        DECLARE @datapath2 varchar(500)=''
        DECLARE @logpath2 varchar(500)=''

        SET @DataPath2 = @datapath+ N'\'+@dbname
        SET @LogPath2 = @logpath+ N'\'+@dbname

        --reading all folders from DATA directory 
        DECLARE @DirTree TABLE (subdirectory nvarchar(255), depth INT)

        INSERT INTO @DirTree(subdirectory, depth)
            EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @DataPath

        --creating a folder on DATA drive with database name if not already exists
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @DirTree WHERE subdirectory = @DBName)
            EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @DataPath2


        DELETE FROM @DirTree

        --reading all folders from LOG directory 
        INSERT INTO @DirTree(subdirectory, depth)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @LogPath

        --creating a folder on LOG drive with database name if not already exists
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @DirTree WHERE subdirectory = @DBName)
            EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @LogPath2

        DECLARE @PhysicalName nvarchar(260)=''
        DECLARE @LogicalName nvarchar(128)=''
        DECLARE @Type char(1)=''
        DECLARE @text nvarchar(2000)=''
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)=''
        DECLARE @restoredb TABLE ( LogicalName nvarchar(128), PhysicalName nvarchar(260),Type char(1)
                ,FileGroupName nvarchar(128),Size numeric(20,0),MaxSize numeric(20,0),FileID bigint,CreateLSN numeric(25,0),DropLSN numeric(25,0)
                ,UniqueID uniqueidentifier,ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0),ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0),BackupSizeInBytes bigint,SourceBlockSize int
                ,FileGroupID int,LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0),DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier
                ,IsReadOnly bit,IsPresent bit,TDEThumbprint varbinary(32),SnapshotUrl nvarchar(128)) 

        --reading header section of backup file
        INSERT @restoredb EXECUTE(N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '''+@backuppath +'''')

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        BEGIN TRY

            --***taking backup of all permissions**********************************
            CREATE TABLE #Permissions (id int identity(1,1), qry nvarchar(4000),Stat bit default 0)

            SET @sql='USE ['+@dbname+'];
            -- Create Users If not exists
            INSERT INTO #Permissions (qry)
            select 
            txt=case when isnull(l.name,'''')=''''
                  then ''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals where name = '''''' + p.name + '''''') BEGIN  CREATE USER ['' + p.name +''] FOR LOGIN ['' + p.name +''] END''
                  else ''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals where name = '''''' + p.name + '''''') BEGIN  CREATE USER ['' + p.name +''] FOR LOGIN ['' + l.name +''] END''
            end
            from sys.database_principals p
            left join master..syslogins l on l.sid = p.sid 
            where p.type NOT IN (''R'') AND p.name NOT IN (''dbo'',''guest'',''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'',''sys'')

            UNION ALL

            --Create Role If not exists
            select 
            txt=case when isnull(l.name,'''')=''''
                  then ''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals where name = '''''' + p.name + '''''') BEGIN CREATE Role ['' + p.name +''] END''
                  else ''''
            end
            from sys.database_principals p
            left join master..syslogins l on l.sid = p.sid
            where p.type =''R'' and  p.name NOT IN (''dbo'',''guest'',''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'',''sys'',
            ''db_owner'',''db_accessadmin'',''db_securityadmin'',''db_ddladmin'',''db_backupoperator'',''db_datareader'',''db_datawriter'',''db_denydatareader'',''db_denydatawriter'',''public'')

            UNION ALL

            --User Permissions
            select 
            txt=case when isnull(p.type ,'''')<>''G''
                 then ''ALTER USER ['' + p.name +''] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ''+ isnull(p.default_schema_name, ''[NULL]'') +'';''
                 else ''''
            end
            + '' EXEC sp_addrolemember '''''' + q.name + '''''', '''''' + p.name + '''''';''

            from sys.database_principals p
            join (select * from sys.database_principals a 
                        join  sys.database_role_members r on a.principal_id=r.role_principal_id) q
                        on q.member_principal_id = p.principal_id
            where (p.type NOT IN (''R'')) AND p.name NOT IN (''dbo'',''guest'',''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'',''sys'')

            UNION ALL

            --Orphaned users
            select 
            txt=case when isnull(l.name,'''')=''''
                 then ''Exec sp_change_users_login ''''update_one'''', '''''' + p.name + '''''', '''''' + p.name + '''''' ''  
                 else ''Exec sp_change_users_login ''''update_one'''', '''''' + p.name + '''''', '''''' + l.name  + '''''' ''
            end
            from sys.database_principals p
            left join master..syslogins l on l.sid = p.sid 
            where p.type=''S'' AND p.name NOT IN (''dbo'',''guest'',''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'',''sys'')

            '

            --get all permissions in text format
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

            --**Permissions end******************************************************************--

            --**preparing a restore statement****************************************************--
            SET @SQL='USE [master];ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                    ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] SET  SINGLE_USER;
                    ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] set offline with NO_WAIT;'

            --set database to single user mode
            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql

            SET @SQL='RESTORE DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] FROM DISK = '''+@backuppath+''' WITH FILE = 1'

            --preparing move statement for all files
            DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT PhysicalName,LogicalName,Type FROM  @restoredb 

            OPEN c1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @PhysicalName,@LogicalName,@Type -- fetch first value

            WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
            BEGIN
                SET  @text = RIGHT(@PhysicalName,CHARINDEX( '\', REVERSE(@PhysicalName)));
                SET @SQL=@SQL+', MOVE '''+@LogicalName+N''''

                IF (@Type = 'L')
                    SET @SQL=@SQL+'   TO '''+@logpath+N'\'+@dbname+@text+N''''
                ELSE
                    SET @SQL=@SQL+'   TO '''+@datapath+N'\'+@dbname+@text+N''''

                FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @PhysicalName,@LogicalName,@Type  -- fetch next value
            END; --WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
            CLOSE c1
            DEALLOCATE c1; 

            -- replace ersetzt die alte db
            SET @SQL=@SQL+', NOUNLOAD , replace , STATS = 10 ;' 

            --perform restore database operation
            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql

            --setting database to online mode    
            SET @SQL='USE [master];
                ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] set ONLINE with NO_WAIT;
                ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] SET  MULTI_USER; '

            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql

            -- changes database owner to sa
            SET @SQL='USE [' + @dbname + N'];
            EXEC sp_changedbowner ''sa'' '

            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql

            --**Database a restore is completed**********************************************--

            --**restore permissions on database****************************************************--
            DECLARE @ptxt nvarchar(4000)='',@Id int=0

            WHILE 0=0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @ptxt='',@Id=0
                SELECT TOP 1 @Id=Id, @ptxt=qry FROM #Permissions WHERE Stat=0 ORDER BY Id        

                IF Isnull(@Id,0)<=0 BREAK;

                SET @ptxt= N'USE [' + @dbname + N'];' + @ptxt

                --skip if any invalid login/user exists
                BEGIN TRY    
                    --print @ptxt
                    EXECUTE (@ptxt)
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    --No action is needed
                END CATCH

                UPDATE #Permissions SET Stat=1 WHERE Id=@Id
            END

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            --setting database to online mode    
            SET @SQL='USE [master];
                ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] set ONLINE with NO_WAIT;
                ALTER DATABASE ['+@dbname+N'] SET  MULTI_USER; '

            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql

            SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY      
            EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
            RECONFIGURE with override

            --Retain original setting
            EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', @XPConfig
            RECONFIGURE with override
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();


            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );
        END CATCH

    END
```

The error message like below:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 69
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 70
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 79
Must declare the scalar variable "@DBName".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 90
Must declare the scalar variable "@DBName".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 105
Must declare the scalar variable "@backuppath".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 116
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 177
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 184
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 198
Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname".
......
```

can anyone explain this for me how to fix this issue if I want to have a pre-check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE PROCEDURE` has to be the only statement in a batch. To conditionally execute it, you can use dynamic SQL.

```
...
IF ...
BEGIN
  EXECUTE(N'CREATE PROCEDURE ...');
END;
...
```

If you only need the conditional execution to prevent errors of the procedure already existing and your version of SQL Server is high enough, you can alternatively use the `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ...` statement. It's available since 2016, I believe. That way the procedure simply gets overwritten, if it already exists, without the statement throwing any errors because of the procedure already existing.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the constraint is `'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.`

Depends on what you want, there are several option, each has different effect.

**`CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`**

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[User_Own_Restore_From_Job]
as
begin
    ...
end;
GO
```

the effect is the procedure is altered and the `modify_date` in `sys.procedures` will be updated every time it executes

**`DROP PROCEDURE` + `CREATE PROCEDURE`**

If you are using a earlier version of `SQL Server` without the `CREATE OR ALTER` option, you can check for existence of the store procedure, drop it and create it.

```
if object_id('dbo.User_Own_Restore_From_Job') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.User_Own_Restore_From_Job
GO

create procedure [dbo].[User_Own_Restore_From_Job]
as
begin
    ...
end;
GO
```

the effect is the procedure is drop and create everytime it executes. And also the `create_date` and `modify_date` will be change also.

**Don't execute if exists**

this make use of [`set noexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) settings. If the procedure exists set `noexec` to `off` (The subsequent commands will not be executed). And set it back to `on` at the end.

```
IF  object_id('dbo.User_Own_Restore_From_Job') is not null
    set noexec on;
GO

create procedure [dbo].[User_Own_Restore_From_Job]
as
begin
    ...
end;
GO

set noexec off;
```